# How to get the % of confidence level for Facebook's Prophet

Tags: python, facebook

I am referring to the recently open-sourced facebook's prophet package that can be used for time-series analysis and predictions.

https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html

If we look at the output of:

`m.plot_components(forecast)`

[image: Output Image]

We see a band around the prediction. What confidence level is that at? I read that the 'uncertainty_level' (set using interval_width hyperparameter) determines the confidence interval / the width of the band around predictions. By default, interval_width = 80%.

So, if the default model predicted # of page views of Peyton Manning's wiki between yhat_lower = 2000 and yhat_upper = 2500 on 2017-01-15; should I interpret that we are **80% confident** that the page views of Peyton Manning's wiki on 2017-01-15 is between 2000 and 2500?

TIA!

Comment: [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14038385) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559473) saying "good question, isn't the confidence interval set in the model generation? m = Prophet(interval_width=0.99, daily_seasonality=True) that would reflect on components too?"